# How to structure React Router routes for different user types using a theme provider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React application where I want to implement different routes for different user types. I also have a ThemeProvider component that provides the theme for the application.Here is my current code structure:

```
export const useMode = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('dark');

  const colorMode = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: () => setMode((prev) => (prev === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light')),
    }),
    []
  );

  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  return { theme, toggleColorMode: colorMode.toggleColorMode };
};

interface RoutesProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const RoutesWithThemeProvider = ({ children }: RoutesProps) => {
  const { theme, toggleColorMode } = useMode();
  const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);
  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={{ toggleColorMode }}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">
          <Sidebar isSidebar={isSidebar} />
          <main className="content">
            <Topbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar} />
            {children}
          </main>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/signup/choice" element={<SignUpChoice />} />
            <Route path="/signup/request/phone-verify" element={<PhoneVerification />} />
            <Route path="/resetpassword" element={<ResetPassword />} />
            <Route path="/email/reset/confirm/:uid/:token" element={<ResetPasswordConfirm />} />
            <Route path="/activate/:uid/:token" element={<Activate />} />
            <Route path="/ride/dashboard" element={<TransportDashboard />} />
            <Route path="/drive/dashboard" element={<DriverDashboard />} />
            <Route path="/about/company" element={<CompanyPage />} />
            <Route path="/company/pricing" element={<Pricing />} />
            <Route path="/how-does-safari-work" element={<HowSafariWorks />} />
            <Route path="/safety/company" element={<Safety />} />
            <Route path="/patnership/company" element={<Patnership />} />
            <Route path="/ride" element={<TransportationRequestPage />} />
            <Route path="/drive" element={<DriveHomePage />} />
            <Route path="/driver/verify" element={<DriverUploadPage />} />
            <Route path="/driver/id" element={<NationalIdVerificationPage />} />
            <Route path="/driver/passport" element={<PassportVerificationPage />} />
            <Route path="/driver/driver-license" element={<DriversLicenseVerificationPage />} />
            <Route
              path="/driver/vehicle-inspection"
              element={<VehicleInspectionCertificatePage />}
            />
            <Route path="/driver/vehicle-insurance" element={<InsuranceCoveragePage />} />
            <Route path="/sign-up/business-form" element={<BusinessFormPage />} />
            <Route path="/business" element={<BusinessHomePage />} />
          </Routes>
          <RoutesWithThemeProvider>
            <Route path="/staff/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/dashboard/overview" element={<Overview />} />
          </RoutesWithThemeProvider>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I want to wrap the routes for staff users with the RoutesWithThemeProvider component, which provides a specific theme and layout. How can I structure my code so that the staff users are directed to their dashboard within the RoutesWithThemeProvider component?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

I tried structuring my code by wrapping the routes for staff users with the RoutesWithThemeProvider component. Here are the steps I followed:

Created a RoutesWithThemeProvider component that wraps the staff routes and provides a specific theme and layout.
Imported the RoutesWithThemeProvider component into my App component.
Wrapped the staff routes inside the RoutesWithThemeProvider component in the Routes component.
Expected the staff routes to be rendered with the provided theme and layout.
However, the actual result was an error message stating that a  should only be used as a child of the  element. It seems that my current code structure is not compatible with the desired outcome.

I'm currently seeking guidance on how to properly structure my code to achieve the desired behavior. Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I made the following changes the code:
I created a new component called StaffRoutesWrapper to wrap the routes for staff users and provide the specific theme and layout. This component uses the useMode hook to access the theme and toggleColorMode function.
Wrapped the staff routes with the StaffRoutesWrapper component in the Routes component. This ensures that the staff routes are rendered within the StaffRoutesWrapper and have access to the desired theme and layout.

```
const StaffRoutesWrapper: React.FC = () => {
  const { theme, toggleColorMode } = useMode();
  const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);
  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={{ toggleColorMode }}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">
          <Topbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar} />
          <Sidebar isSidebar={isSidebar} />
          <main className="content">            
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/business" element={<BusinessHomePage />} />
              {/* <Outlet /> */}
            </Routes>
          </main>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
};


const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/signup/choice" element={<SignUpChoice />} />
            <Route path="/signup/request/phone-verify" element={<PhoneVerification />} />
            <Route path="/resetpassword" element={<ResetPassword />} />
            <Route path="/email/reset/confirm/:uid/:token" element={<ResetPasswordConfirm />} />
            <Route path="/activate/:uid/:token" element={<Activate />} />
            <Route path="/ride/dashboard" element={<TransportDashboard />} />
            <Route path="/drive/dashboard" element={<DriverDashboard />} />
            <Route path="/about/company" element={<CompanyPage />} />
            <Route path="/company/pricing" element={<Pricing />} />
            <Route path="/how-does-safari-work" element={<HowSafariWorks />} />
            <Route path="/safety/company" element={<Safety />} />
            <Route path="/patnership/company" element={<Patnership />} />
            <Route path="/ride" element={<TransportationRequestPage />} />
            <Route path="/drive" element={<DriveHomePage />} />
            <Route path="/driver/verify" element={<DriverUploadPage />} />
            <Route path="/driver/id" element={<NationalIdVerificationPage />} />
            <Route path="/driver/passport" element={<PassportVerificationPage />} />
            <Route path="/driver/driver-license" element={<DriversLicenseVerificationPage />} />
            <Route
              path="/driver/vehicle-inspection"
              element={<VehicleInspectionCertificatePage />}
            />
            <Route path="/driver/vehicle-insurance" element={<InsuranceCoveragePage />} />
            <Route path="/sign-up/business-form" element={<BusinessFormPage />} />
            <Route path="/business" element={<BusinessHomePage />} />

            {/* Wrap the staff routes with the StaffRoutesWrapper */}
            <Route path="/staff/*" element={<StaffRoutesWrapper />} />
          </Routes>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

With these changes, the staff users are now directed to their dashboard within the StaffRoutesWrapper component, which provides the specific theme and layout.

Overall, this solution allowed me to achieve the desired behavior of having different routes for different user types and providing a specific theme and layout for staff users.